# Loop through a two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "http://google.com",
        "Google"
    ),

    array(
        "http://yahoo.com",
        "Yahoo"
    )
);
```

What is the simplest way to loop through it. Something like:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    // help
}
```

EDIT: How do I target keys, for example, I want to do:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    echo '<a href" $key1 ">';
    echo ' $key2 </a>';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `$key1` and `$key2`?

Comment: @PleaseWait Please see my updated array and it will make better sense.

Comment: Your design seems weird to me. Why would you want a 2D array for those values instead of something like this:

$array = array("Google" => "http://google.com", "Yahoo" => "http://yahoo.com");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to echo out the bits you have to select their index in each array -

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    echo '<a href="'.$arr[0].'">'.$arr[1].'</a>';
}
```

Here is an [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/pcjr-6j91).

Answer (score 8):

Use nested `foreach()` because it is 2D array. Example here

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){ 
    // Here $val is also array like ["Hello World 1 A","Hello World 1 B"], and so on
    // And $key is index of $array array (ie,. 0, 1, ....)
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){ 
        // $v is string. "Hello World 1 A", "Hello World 1 B", ......
        // And $k is $val array index (0, 1, ....)
        echo $v . '<br />';
    }
}
```

In first `foreach()` `$val` is also an array. So a nested `foreach()` is used. In second `foreach()` `$v` is string.

**Updated according to your demand**

```
foreach($array as $val){
    echo '<a href="'.$val[0].'">'.$val[1].'</a>';
}
```

Comment: How do I target a key? For example I want to add $key1 somewhere within the foreach loop, and $key2 somewhere else.

Comment: Please see my updated question for an explanation of my request.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to loop through it is:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $index=>$value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

If you know that your array will have always only two indexes then you can try this:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    echo "<a href='$arr[0]'>$arr[1]</a>";
}
```

Comment: But how do I target a key? For example I want to add $key1 somewhere within the foreach loop, and $key2 somewhere else.

Comment: Please see my updated question for an explanation of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

First modify your variable like this:

```
$array = array(
          array("url"=>"http://google.com",
                "name"=>"Google"
          ),
          array("url"=>"http://yahoo.com",
                "name"=>"Yahoo"
          ));
```

then you can loop like this:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{ 
   echo '<a href='.$value["url"].'>'.$value["name"].'</a>'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to loop through is,

```
foreach($array as $arr)
foreach($arr as $string) {
        //perform any action using $string
}
```

Use the first foreach loop without `{ }` for the **simplest** use.

That can be the most simple method to use a nested array as per your request.

For your edited question.

Wrong declaration of array for using key.

```
$array = array( 
    "http://google.com" => "Google",
    "http://yahoo.com" => "Yahoo" );
```

And then, use the following.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    echo "<a href='{$key}'>{$value}</a>";
```

This doesn't slow down your server's performance.

Comment: How do I target the keys though? See my edited answer please.

Comment: do you want to use the key using foreach or the simplest for loop version?

Comment: Simplest way of looping through it, see my updated array to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: is it okay @HenrikPetterson?

Comment: Is this the best approach when considering server performance? Thank you for the update by the way!

Answer (score 2):

In modern versions of php, you can assign (destructure) subarray values to variables of your choosing.

A good tutorial: https://stitcher.io/blog/array-destructuring-with-list-in-php

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DXc5J))

```
$array = [
    ["http://example1.com", "Example 1"],
    ["http://example2.com", "Example 2"]
];

foreach ($array as [$key1, $key2]) {
    echo "<a href=\"$key1\">$key2</a>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://example1.com">Example 1</a>
<a href="http://example2.com">Example 2</a>
```

To be honest, I'd probably name the variables `$url` and `$text` respectively.