# Split Minecraft Player Bans File (banned-players,json) Each Time A Ban Is Found

Tags: php, arrays, json, ftp, minecraft

I'm trying to create a page on my website to list the bans on my Minecraft server.
I'm getting the file via FTP (don't tell me that this is a security issue)

Here is my Code:

```
$banfile = file_get_contents("ftp://**********262%40gmail.com.*****:**********@***.***.*.***:21/banned-players.json");
$banarray = json_decode($banfile, true);
echo print_r($banarray, true);`
```

but i'm getting the players out of the array. I can get a specific number ban out of the file but when a new one is added I can't get this one because the script is unaware that it exists

This is the [output](https://pastebin.com/Jh3BScPd). (Put into an array by the code; sensitive info was hidden. Put on Pastebin so I don't spam the question)

I want to put them in a table format:

Head:
**Player** | **Reason** | **Banned By** | **Expire Time**

Row:
ExamplePlayer | Reasons | Admin | never

With the current code this is somewhat do-able with getting it from the array and echoing it:

Row:

```
$banarray[0][name] | $banarray[0][reason] | $banarray[0][source] | $banarray[0][expires]
```

This code would work but I would have to update this page manually quite often. I know that there is a php function `foreach (array_expression as $value)` but I have no idea how to use this. I do believe that for what I want to do a `foreach()` is needed.

Comment: Please include your coding attempt to display the array as a table.  By implementing a `foreach()` loop, you shouldn't need to "update the page manually" ever.

Comment: PHPglue I have an understanding of arrays, otherwise how did I come up with translating JSON into an array and getting a value out of the array? `$banarrav[0][name]`?? and mickmackusa I havent attempted to do the table because I was unaware of how the foreach funcion worked..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through a two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591105/loop-through-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($banarray as $v) {
    echo $v['name'], ' | ', $v['reason'],' | ', $v['source'], ' | ', $v['expires'], "\n";
}
```

so in $v is current element that you can ommit [0], [1],...

Answer (score 0):

Just you can access your elements from an array using a loop.

```
foreach ($banarray as $value) {
  echo 'source => ' . $value['source'] . '<br>';
  echo 'reason => ' . $value['reason'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like:

```
<?php
$rows = '';
foreach($banarray as $a){
  $rows .= "<tr><td>{$a['uuid']}</td><td>{$a['name']}</td>"
    ."<td>{$a['created']}</td><td>{$a['source']}</td>"
    ."<td>{$a['expires']}</td><td>{$a['reason']}</td></tr>";
}
$table = "<table id='tbl'><thead><tr><th>uuid</th><th>name</th>"
  .'<th>created</th><th>source</th><th>expires</th><th>reason</th></tr>'
  ."<thead><tbody>$rows</tbody></table>";
echo $table;
?>
```